# Having problems with ContentProvider data binding

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I wanted to learn how ContentProviders worked as well as preventing my app from crashing when rotated before binding the asynctask's returned data, so I decided to add them to the first Spotify project. One difference between all the examples I have seen was that, in the case of this app, I am not storing the data in sqlite so instead of using the SqliteCursor I am using the MatrixCursor. However, I am pretty sure that the issue that I am having is unrelated.

In the fragment's onCreateView method I am make a call to .query(), which is received by my content provider that returns no data which is expected since a search has not yet been performed. After entering some search text the api call is made and data is returned. I then do a bulkInsert() on the provider and then call .notifyChange() method. This is where I would expect the cursor bound in the onCreateView in my fragment to make perform an update by calling the .query() method of the contentProvider again, but it doesn't.

I have compared my project against the Udacity project of the branch that matches where I am and can't see any differences that would cause this issue. There is quite a bit of code to post here, and unless I post it all I would probably end up leaving something out some of you might want to take a look at, so below is a link to my github branch with these changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And if I'm way off track in trying to use a ContentProvider for a search like this let me know :)

https://github.com/chrisolsen/coursera-spotify/tree/content-provider/app/src/main/java/org/chrisolsen/spotify

The content provider is being called from the artist search fragment https://github.com/chrisolsen/coursera-spotify/blob/content-provider/app/src/main/java/org/chrisolsen/spotify/ArtistSearchActivityFragment.java

Comment: please post specific parts of your code and not a link to your whole project

Comment: As I mentioned, all the code in the linked folder is required, but I added a link to point to the start point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is where I would expect the cursor bound in the onCreateView in
>   my fragment to perform an update by calling the .query() method
>   of the contentProvider again, but it doesn't.

All of my experience is with `ContentProviders` using an SQLite database. I also am not very familiar with early Android versions.  With those caveats, I'll say that I am nearly certain that `Cursor` has never done automatic re-queries in response to a CP data change notification.  As described in the [docs for Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), there are methods to specify a `ContentObserver` and `Uri` to monitor, but those are just hooks for you (or a loader--see below) to add re-query logic.

Because many CPs use SQLite DBs or other storage that cannot be accessed on the main thread, a common pattern for querying a `ContentProvider` is to use a [CursorLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).  A `CursorLoader` **does** react to a data change notification by re-querying and delivering an updated cursor. This [CursorLoader guide](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html) may be helpful, although because you are storing your artist data in memory, you don't need the background thread features. If your storage design evolves to use an SQLite DB, `CursorLoader` and the [Loader framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. With the notifyCursor() call I was under the impression that would allow for the data displayed to be kept sync.  I knew using a loader was the way to go, but was under the impression that was only to keep things running on a non-UI thread; so a good practice, but not required.  After using a loader everything works as expected.